# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Tags: spring-boot

I'm new to spring-boot and I'm testing spring-boot application using http API, but I got connection error.

> GET http://localhost:8080/api/helloworld
>
> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8080 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

```
//HelloWorldController.java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
    @GetMapping(value="/api/helloworld")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

```
//helloworld.http    
GET http://localhost:8080/api/helloworld
```

And It works well with running main java file.

[image]

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: When you say `helloworld.http`, what is it exactly ? Are you sure your server is up and running when you execute your tests ? Could you please provide your test class ?

Comment: Oh thank you! That was stupid of me,, I turned on the server and it works

Comment: Don't worry, we all went through something like that... You'll get use to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running npm install. In the server.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).